# MetricBeat - Kafka's consumergroup metricset doesn't send any data?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metrics, metricbeat

I have running ZooKeeper and single Kafka broker and I want to get metrics with MetricBeat, index it with ElasticSearch and display with Kibana.

However, MetricBeat can only get data from `partition` metricset and nothing comes from `consumergroup` metricset.

Since `kafka` module is defined as periodical in `metricbeat.yml`, it should send some data on it's own, not just waiting for users interaction (f.exam. - write to topic) ?
To ensure myself, I tried to create consumer group, write and consume from topic, but still no data was collected by `consumergroup` metricset.

`consumergroup` is defined in both `metricbeat.template.json` and `metricbeat.template-es2x.json`.

While `metricbeat.full.yml` is completely commented off, this is my `metricbeat.yml` kafka module definition :

```
- module: kafka
  metricsets: ["partition", "consumergroup"]
  enabled: true
  period: 10s

  hosts: ["localhost:9092"]

  client_id: metricbeat1
  retries: 3
  backoff: 250ms

  topics: []
```

In `/logs` directory of MetricBeat, lines like this show up :

```
INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s:
libbeat.es.published_and_acked_events=109
libbeat.es.publish.write_bytes=88050 
libbeat.publisher.messages_in_worker_queues=109             
libbeat.es.call_count.PublishEvents=5
fetches.kafka-partition.events=106
fetches.kafka-consumergroup.success=2
libbeat.publisher.published_events=109
libbeat.es.publish.read_bytes=2701
fetches.kafka-partition.success=2
fetches.zookeeper-mntr.events=3
fetches.zookeeper-mntr.success=3
```

With ZooKeeper's `mntr` and Kafka's `partition`, I can see `events=` and `success=` values, but for `consumergroup` there is only `success`. It looks like no events are fired.

`partition` and `mntr` data are properly visible in Kibana, while `consumergroup` is missing.

Data stored in ElasticSearch are not readable with human eye, there are some internal strings used for directory names and logs do not contain any useful information.

Can anybody help me to understand what is going on and fix it(probably MetricBeat) to send data to ElasticSearch ? Thanks :)

Comment: same problem for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an active consumer consuming out of the topics, to be able to generate events for `consumergroup` metricset.

Comment: As this is quite old problem, I don't remember - but I think there was 
active consumer. I will close this question, since I have chosen different monitoring.